# Rewrite the SQL in version 5.7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a following SQL which works in mysql version 5.6 but is breaking in mysql version 5.7.x.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM photos WHERE photoable_type = 'Mobilehome'
AND photoable_id IN (SELECT id FROM mobilehomes WHERE
mobilehomes.community_id = 1) AND photos.image_file_size IS NOT NULL 
AND photos.is_published IS TRUE ORDER BY photos.priority ASC) AS tmp_table
GROUP BY photoable_id
```

It's throwing me following error:

```
 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
   nonaggregated column 'tmp_table.id' which is not functionally 
    dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is 
    incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: The error is clear. It's telling you that you can't use a GROUP BY with `SELECT *`. GROUP BY is for aggregating data, and you're not aggregating data using MIN, MAX, AVG, or SUM in your outer query. It's sad that it ever worked at all. If you want it rewritten, find a SQL tutorial, learn the proper way to use GROUP BY, and make an effort to rewrite it yourself.

Comment: why you are using group by without aggregation function  .. ?  . what is your expected  result for 5.6  ..  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case or you change the sql mode  for instrcut the db to work as mysql 5.6 version or you can adeguate your query to the new behavior

In this second case
If you use group by whithout aggregation function  this mean that for all the column different from photoable_id you accept casual result

This mean that you could, probably, also accepted  an aggregated result based greagtion function eg: on min() or max ()

assuming your tables containg col1, col2,   ..  the you must declare explicitally the column you need

```
  SELECT photos.photoable_id, min(col1), min(col2),.... 
  FROM photos 
  INNER JOIN mobilehomes ON mobilehomes.community_id = 1 
      AND photos.photoable_type = 'Mobilehome'
        AND photos.photoable_id = mobilehomes.id
  AND photos.image_file_size IS NOT NULL 
  AND photos.is_published IS TRUE 

  GROUP BY photos.photoable_id
  ORDER BY photos.priority ASC
```

Looking to your code seems also that you could avoid the subquery